# How to wait for CloudFormation stack to update with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Given that you're using the AWS Ruby SDK (2.0), how to wait for a CloudFormation stack to update?

Answer (score 2):

The waiter passes an updated [Stack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudFormation/Stack.html#stack_status-instance_method) instance into the given block every `delay` seconds for `max_attempts`.

```
# @client is your client
stack = Aws::CloudFormation::Stack.new(name, :client => @client)
stack(stage).wait_until({delay: 15, max_attempts: 20}) do |i|
  i.stack_status == 'STACK_UPDATE_COMPLETE' 
end
```